# How to tell if type punning is ok on my platform?

Tags: c++, type-punning

I have a bunch of code taking binary blobs from network. On knowing the type of the blob I've so far used type punning (pseudo):

```
uint8_t* data = network.get();
if(type == "A") {
  uint32_t* var = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(data);
  ...
} else if (type == "B") {
  float* var = reinterpret_cast<float*>(data);
  ...
}
```

And in some places there are unions:

```
union A {
  float valf;
  uint32_t valu;
};
```

And this would seem to work fine, but now I read posts on type punning like this is UB as per standard and that I should use memcpy instead. Yet, it provably works on many platforms.

Q1: Is there a way to test if type punning is supported and behaves as expected on my platform?

Q2: Can I expect mainstream compilers (MSVC, GCC) to warn or error on illegal type punning on my platform?

Comment: You could just write your code to follow the Standard and not have to worry about any of this

Comment: @M.M For new code, yes. Rewrite legacy code though? Not convinced. Also memcpy means using more memory and do more, well, memory copy.

Comment: In C, you would want to do two things: get the binary data as `char*`, and then use `memcpy` to convert the data, something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/hDqkC6). Note that there is no copying involved at all, with optimizations enabled. **(update: you just removed the C tag, never mind)**.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "okay on your platform". Your code is obviously relying on two distinct processes (programs) doing things in compatible ways so that the code always works. If you've adequately verified that the processes work and interact as you intend, are confident that a change of compiler (used to build either program) won't break things, etc etc  then it may well be "okay on your platform". Personally, I'd try to find a way that doesn't rely on some combination of undefined/unspecified behaviour - type punning has uses but too many pitfalls to justify it as a default choice.

Comment: Type-punning using unions is forbidden in C++, and leads to UB. Only the last written-to member can be read from. It can't really be enforced by compilers though, since they can't tell how a union is used at run-time.

Comment: @Groo Cool! Got me thinking. If type punning is ok on my platform, my compiler may optimize for it. Meaning there should be no perf hit for a decent compiler.

Comment: You can alway study the generated assembly and manuals for your processor architecture ;-).

Comment: @Andreas The memcpy idiom is well known and tends to be recognized by compilers – at least by non-ancient ones. Your chances are good that there won’t be any extra copies in an optimized build.

Comment: @DanielLangr I'd rather refactor everything ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1: Is there a way to test if type punning is supported and behaves as expected on my platform?

Yes, read the compiler manual. There is usually a chapter about non-standard extensions. For example [gcc C extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) or [gcc C++ extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions). If there is no documented non-standard extension (or in case you compile for strict standard compliance), you have to assume that using such code is unsafe and undefined behavior.

gcc in particular is traditionally infamous for invoking undefined behavior upon strict pointer aliasing violations. You can block it from exploiting that UB during optimizations with `-f-no-strict-aliasing`.

Type punning through unions is well-defined in C but undefined in C++.

> Q2: Can I expect mainstream compilers (MSVC, GCC) to warn or error on illegal type punning on my platform?

No, this is very rare. In general, you can't expect diagnostic messages upon invoking undefined behavior. This is why there's still a market for static analyser tools. Also, many forms of undefined behavior occur in run-time.

Answer (score 2):

> Q2: Can I expect mainstream compilers (MSVC, GCC) to warn or error on illegal type punning on my platform?

Not always, you'll get false positives, even if you enable all warnings and use static analysis (e.g. with [recent GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) or [Clang](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)). See [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

You could write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to validate your project's coding rules (perhaps inspired by [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_10:_Rules_for_Developing_Safety-Critical_Code)).

This [draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) gives much more details and references.

Practically speaking, you cannot avoid [code reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) by senior developers (perhaps external to your team). Be aware of the [Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/). In your software development projects, do budget some code review efforts. Read [*The Mythical Man-Month*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month) book.